# CSS hover answers not working for my code

Tags: css, hover

I've been trying a couple of answers from here but none seem to work for me, what am I doing wrong? The only time I get anything similar to desired is starting with a img in the div but then I have multiple (if I use no-repeat it stops hovering again).

The plan is to go from blured to clear over 500ms or something but for now I'd just like the image swap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>     
<style type='text/css'>
.imgBox { background-image: url('preA.png'); }
.imgBox:hover { background-image: url('post.png'); }
</style>
</head><body>    
<div class="imgBox">
<img src='preA.png' />
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do blurs with CSS (look up Blur filter). Don't know if you are on a browser requirement.

Comment: BTW, quotes are not required when specifying a file URL.

Comment: It is good practice to use quote marks though I have found (helps with certain characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `img` tag inside your `div`, other than as a placeholder to make sure the `div` is the right size.  This is your problem, since that image does not disappear with the CSS styles you have specified.  You can make it do so and fix your problem.

```css
.imgBox { background: url('http://placehold.it/140/ffffff/000000') no-repeat; }
.imgBox:hover { background: url('http://placehold.it/140/000000/ffffff') no-repeat; }
.imgBox:hover img { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="imgBox">
<img src='http://placehold.it/140/ffffff/000000' />
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I think part of my problem was using background-image with no-repeat instead of background

Comment: Yes, I've made that mistake too, you either need to use the `background` shorthand, or two separate styles `background-image` and `background-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use hover without initial `src=""` by using `:before` in css

```
.imgBox:before { content: url('preA.png');background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.imgBox:hover:before { content: url('post.png');background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zj49dcu8/)

Comment: @LcSalazar: i was adding the description.. :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me in FF. I just have an empty white page if I remove the img src

Comment: @Dird: sorry,i have edited my code..please check again change background-image top content and changed hover selector

Comment: That works but so did the other. I guess I prefer the other to have it sitting in HTML too but both correct.